# Given two sequences of infinite random numbers generated in each iteration, will the sequences ever be equal given infinite iterations?

Tags: sequences-and-series, random

First is, does this question even make sense? I know that infinity is a concept of endlessness but people seem to use it a lot, assuming infinity can be reached, to get a solution. Can it be applied here? I'm not a mathematician. I'm just curious.

By equal, I mean that the two sequences have all the same numbers from the beginning to infinity.
Also does it matter to the question if each item in the sequence is finite or is infinite? For example, if two people flips a coin an infinite number of times you only have two possibilities for each item in the two sequences (heads or tails). Does that make a difference to the answer compared to having no limit for each item in the sequence?

Comment: Obviously not. Why would they be equal?

Comment: @DonThousand Can it's never being equal be explained? Or is it simply intuition?

Comment: It can be explained, but it requires a level of sophistication that I don't believe you currently have. I do recommend learning more about infinity, as part of being able to answer these sorts of questions is making sure you actually understand the terms you use.

Comment: mathematicians are for sure willing to consider infinite sequences. If you have one never-ending sequence and I have another one, we can wonder if they are equal. Is that what you mean by "two sequences"? What does NOT make sense to me in your text is "limit for each item in the sequence".

Comment: @311411 Yes that's what I meant by "two sequences." What I mean by limit for each item is for example each item can only be 1 and 2, randomly, and nothing else. Like a series of coin flips.

Comment: Aha, brendt, thanks for clarifying. If you get into math more you will find that the word "limit" has a very special meaning, different from how you used the word. In fact, you can see "lim" in Stork's answer below.

Comment: @311411 Thanks for that! Replaced it with finite/infinite instead of limit/nolimit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chance the first digits are equal is $P_1 = 1/10$.  The chance that the first $n$ digits are equal is $P_n = (1/10)^n$.  The chance that an infinite number of digits are equal is:

$$P_\infty = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{10} \right)^n \to 0$$